# Closing a dynamically created jQuery-ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a user information edit dialog that fetches edit-user information using `$.post` but I'm unable to close this dialog since dialog wasn't initialized using any HTML element.

I am trying `$('#editUser').dialog('close')` but it won't work.

Here is the main body:

```
<div id='userInfo'>
<div class='user'>
    <span class='userId'>1</span>
    <span class='userName'>John</span>
</div>
<div class='user'>
    <span class='userId'>2</span>
    <span class='userName'>Jane</span>
</div>
```

and here is the script used to create the dialog:

```
$(function() {
$('.user').click(function() {
     var uid = $(this).find('span.userId').html();
    $post('/e-val/user/edit.php', {id: uid}, function(html) {
       $(html).dialog();
    });
});

$('body').on('click', '#closeEditDialog', function() {
   $('#editUser').dialog('close')
});
});
```

The dialog opens up fine as expected but isn't closing as it should.

This is the HTML for the dialog as returned by the ajax script.

```
<div id='editUser'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><?php echo $user['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><?php echo $user['email'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
<input type='button' id='closeEditDialog' value='close' />
</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**What can I do to close it?** I can use `$('#editUser').remove()` to remove the dialog, but I need to close it not remove it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually create the dialog. When you call  $('#editUser').dialog('close') do you get anything in your browsers error console?

Comment: its already there in the javascript. No, I am not getting anything on firebug console.

Comment: Is there anything different between your code and this example: http://jsfiddle.net/T9AQx/ (besides the AJAX requests)

Comment: Also, what is `$post`. Do you mean `$.post` instead?

Comment: Here's another example that *is* using AJAX: http://jsfiddle.net/wetvn/. It looks like the dialog works fine the first time but then gets messed up subsequent times. Is this the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#editUser').dialog('close')` won't work because you've never used `$('#editUser')` to initialize the `dialog`, so you cannot use it either to close it, You need to use the same handler that was used to create it.

As answered here by Gil & Trinh :
Just add the dialog content to the DOM first and then initialize the dialog:

```
$post('/e-val/user/edit.php', {id: uid}, function(html) {
   $(html).appendTo('body');
   $('#editUser').dialog( {autoOpen: false} );
});
```

`autoOpen: false` will prevent the dialog from opening by itself and it can be opened using `$('#editUser').dialog('open')` anytime.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mydialog;
$(function() {
$('.user').click(function() {
     var uid = $(this).find('span.userId').html();
    $post('/e-val/user/edit.php', {id: uid}, function(html) {
       mydialog = $(html);
       mydialog.appendTo('body');
       mydialog.dialog();
    });
});

$('body').on('click', '#closeEditDialog', function() {
   mydialog.dialog('close')
});
});
```

Comment: or `mydialog = $(html); mydialog.dialog()` plz try

Comment: please install firebug or firefox console and copy return error

Comment: And can you try `$(html).appendTo('body').dialog();`

Comment: the dialog is working fine! but it it won't close on clicking close.

Comment: Because you havent add it to DOM, so you cannot select it by ID. Have to append to document.body first

Comment: Calling `.dialog` will append the content to the DOM in order to show it.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to insert that html into your DOM before creating your dialog.

```
$("body").append(html);
$("#editUser").dialog();
```

Well at least if your dialog shows up this way, there is nothing preventing it from closing, you're using the same selector.

**EDIT**

Also, do not forget that .dialog() will initialize the widget, try not calling it more than once. Using .dialog("open") instead.

Best would be even to already add the dialog's div into your html, and then append your server side code in it to dynamically update the content of the dialog.